# Inorder traversal Printing Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree, traversal, inorder

I am working on a Binary search tree and right now I am working on having my inorder traversal be printed the way I want it to. I mostly figured it out but there is one tiny error in the way in which I want it to come out. Currently it prints out as [ -1, 8, 9, 12, 13, 17, 19,  ]. I want to get rid of that extra comma and space at the end so that it looks like this. [ -1, 8, 9, 12, 13, 17, 19 ]. I would appreciate any help I could get. Also any suggestions to make it more efficient is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in inorder` will traverse the elements of the array so `i != len(inorder)` will compare element to the len of the array **not** the index location

try

```
for i in range(len(inorder)):
  a += str(inorder[i])
  if i != len(inorder) - 1:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
for i in range(len(inorder)):
  a +=  str(inorder[i])
  if i < len(inorder)-1:
      a += ", "
```

Comment: sadly that gives me [ -1, 8912131719 ]